# Centos 7 - Text Mode Setup Utility (Setup Command) - Missing "Network Configuration"

Tags: linux, configuration, installation, centos, centos7

How to make "Network Configuration" option to show up in "Text Mode Setup Utility" (Setup Command) in **Centos 7**

[image]

- This Centos 7 was installed with "Infrastructure Server" setup.
- I have tried "yum groups install" with following groups, but it didn't resolve the issue:

Networking Tools
System Management
System Administration Tools

- Please advise what should I install or enable on **Centos 7** to get "Text Mode Setup Utility" to has "Network Configuration"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NetworkManager TUI instead of setuptool

```
nmtui
```

if not installed install it

```
yum install NetworkManager-tui
```

[image]